# NoFollow Rel="sponsored" pre_replace

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace, nofollow

I use wordpress, I've added a bit of code to my functions.php to automatically all links as no-follow that don't meet certain conditions.

Currently, if the link `examplesite.com` or `examplesite2.com` mark as `dofollow` else set to `nofollow`

The code that I use to achieve that (which works perfectly) is:

```
function add_nofollow_content($content) {
$content = preg_replace_callback(
'/<a[^>]*href=["|\']([^"|\']*)["|\'][^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/i',
function($m) {
if (strpos($m[1], "https://www.examplesite.com") === false && strpos($m[1], "https://www.examplesite2.com") === false)
return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
else
return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
},
$content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_nofollow_content');
```

However, I want to add an additional condition.

If the site is `examplesite` or `examplesite2.com`  mark it as `rel="follow"`

elseif

if it's `examplesite3.com` or `examplesite4.com` mark it as `rel=”sponsored”`

else (if it doesn't meet either of those conditions return

`no Follow`  instead.

could someone help me with this? I tried adding

```
function add_nofollow_content($content) {
$content = preg_replace_callback(
'/<a[^>]*href=["|\']([^"|\']*)["|\'][^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/i',
function($m) {
if (strpos($m[1], "https://www.examplesite.com") === false && strpos($m[1], "https://www.examplesite2.com") === false && strpos($m[1], "https://examplesite3.com") === false && strpos($m[3], "https://examplesite4.com") === false)
return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
else
return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="sponsored" target="_blank">'.$m[3].'</a>';
},
$content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_nofollow_content');
```

But it created a loop and didn't work. Thank you in advance for any ideas!

and I also tried this one, altering the `elseif` but it doesn't seem to get past the 2nd condition.

```
function add_nofollow_content($content) {
$content = preg_replace_callback(
'/<a[^>]*href=["|\']([^"|\']*)["|\'][^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/i',
function($m) {
if (strpos($m[1], "https://www.examplesite.com") === false && strpos($m[1], "https://www.examplesite2.com") === false && strpos($m[3], "https://www.bluehost.com") === false && strpos($m[3], "https://amzn.to") === false)
return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
elseif (strpos($m[3], "https://www.examplesponsor.com") === false && strpos($m[3], "https://www.examplesponsor2.com") === false && strpos($m[3], "https://examplesponsor3.com") === false)
return '<a href="'.$m[3].'" rel="sponsored" target="_blank">'.$m[4].'</a>';
        else
return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
},
$content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_nofollow_content');
```

Comment: This code sample you posted is really incomplete. The `preg_replace_callback` isn't closed properly, and the definition of the `add_nofollow_content` function is missing. There's no way to check out what caused this loop.

Comment: Ok, but the first one works, I'm just trying to add in a condition that if it's `xyz.com` site then return `rel="sponsored"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
function add_nofollow_content($content) {
  $content = preg_replace_callback(
    '/<a[^>]*href=["|\']([^"|\']*)["|\'][^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/i',
    function($m) {
      if ((strpos($m[1], "https://www.examplesite.com") !== false) ||
          (strpos($m[1], "https://www.examplesite2.com") !== false)) {
        return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="follow" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
      } elseif ((strpos($m[1], "https://www.examplesite3.com") !== false) ||
                (strpos($m[1], "https://www.examplesite4.com") !== false)) {
        return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="sponsored" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
      } else {
        return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
      }
    },
    $content);
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_nofollow_content');
```

This checks if either of the two URLs is found using strpos and returns the appropriate `rel=` for each case. For all other URLs, it will return `rel="nofollow"`. In case you have to define more  URLs, make sure to logically `||` them as well.

For a seriously longer list of URLs, I'd change the code structure to do an array mapping of URL → rel type and loop over the entries matching each one against the match.